# Error installing Ubuntu , how to remove and install it again

Tags: installation, wubi

I am having problem in installing ubuntu in my windows 7. I had installed it earlier using Wubi but it got corrupted and now because of it i am not able to install any of the ubuntu version in Windows 7 via wubi. Someone please help me it is really getting frustrating.
This is the error i have got

> Exception: Error executing command
>
> command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /create /d Ubuntu
>   /application bootsector retval=1 stderr=The boot configuration data
>   store could not be opened. The configuration registry database is
>   corrupt.

Is there any way which will make my windows boot clean and remove ubuntu entry and let me install again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wubi boot registry corrupted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164210/wubi-boot-registry-corrupted)

Comment: if this gets closed, would you consider merging tjiybba's answer?  thanks.  my close direction was based on date/time asked

Answer (score 5):

First , you need to **Uninstall Wubi** from windows , as you remove/uninstall any Program in windows or through any Uninstaller Utility.

if that doesn't help then Use this Specific  [**Unistall Wubi**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe) tool from here [**How do i uninstall Wubi**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/) and also refer the **How do I manually uninstall Wubi?**.

**How do I reinstall Wubi?**

Run **Wubi.exe** again `( After the above uninstallation process)`. Wubi will detect that there is an existing installation and you will be offered an option to uninstall. You may want to backup the installation files (the ISO) in order to avoid having to download them again. Note that when you reinstall, the system virtual drive **(root.disk)** is reset.

**Recommendation**

I would highly advise you to use Ubuntu in **Dual-Boot setup**, and **not through Wubi**. You can refer this guide to install it.

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to uninstall wubi is to go to run C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-ubuntu.exe . Otherwise you can remove it through control panel -> Programs and features. 
And as tjybba said you should use Ubuntu in DUal-Boot setup. This would ensure that you can use one OS without disturbing the other one.

Comment: Aarti i have tried all and even if i want to intall ubuntu in Dual boot setup thing is i have licensed Windows 7 copy and the toshiba has given me a recovery DVD and this DVD creates two partition on its own. So thats why i intsalled it under windows and if u shud know Ubuntu runs Without any problem if installed under windows like a normal standalone Ubuntu